# The exact height of a text line (font-size + line-height)

Tags: html, css, height, font-size

How can a text line be controlled exactly from the height point of view?

I mean, it appears that the font-size and line-height are not giving the *span* (or other inline element) its exact height.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghxgouba/

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" />
    <span>salut</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
span {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: darkblue;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The *span* is 56px height, where it should be exactly 50px, shouldn't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line-height works only with the block-level elements, which mean you need to apply `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your span to have `line-height` working. Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghxgouba/3/

```css
span {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: darkblue;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
#ret {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Another interesting thing is that even if you control the line-height and you'll have its exact height, a bigger text will pull down the elements beneath it. http://jsfiddle.net/ghxgouba/5/

Comment: if you want to limit space for text only to it's line-height, then add overflow: hidden; which will crop too large text

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` for the `span` element, then you will get exactly the same height as the image. http://jsfiddle.net/ghxgouba/1/

(For a normal inline element, the height calculation based on font size and line height just works different. For more, consult the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height)